# How to achieve pagination with results from a list in web.py python

Tags: python, list, pagination, tuples, web.py

I am using python `web.py` to design a small web app , here actually i am not using any database for fetching results/records, i will have a list of records(which i will get from some where according to requirement :) )

Below is my code

**code.py**

```
import web
from web import form

urls = (
    '/', 'index',
    '/urls', 'urls_result',
)

app =  web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/')

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.home()

    def POST(self):
        result_list = [('Images', 'http://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi'), 
                       ('Maps', 'http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl'), 
                       ('Play', 'https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8'), 
                       ('YouTube', 'http://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN&tab=w1'), 
                       ('News', 'http://news.google.co.in/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn'),  
                       ('Gmail', 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm'), 
                       ('Drive', 'https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo'), 
                       ('More&raquo;', 'http://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/'), 
                       ('Web History', 'http://www.google.co.in/history/optout?hl=en'), 
                       ('Settings', 'http://www.google.co.in/preferences?hl=en'), 
                       ('Sign in', 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.co.in/'), 
                       ('Advanced search', 'http://www.google.co.in/advanced_search?hl=en-IN&authuser=0'),
                       .............. 
                       ..............
                       .............. so on until 200 records      ]
        return render.recordslist(result_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**home.html**

```
$def with()
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Home Page</title>
  <body alink="green" link="blue" >
    <div class="main">
      <center>
              <form method="POST" action='urls'>
                  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
      </center>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**recordslist.html**

```
$def with(result_list)
<html>
 <head>
    <title>List of records</title> 
 </head>
 <body> 
   <table>
     $for link in result_list:
     <tr>
        <td>$link[0]</td>
        <td>$link[1]</td>
     </tr>    
   </table> 
 </body>
```

So from the above code what i am doing is, when i run the server and hit the browser with ip returned from `web.py`, it is redirected to home page (with url `/` and template as `home.html`) which consists of form with a single button.

Now here i am not using any `database` to fetch the records, simply i have hardcored records which are in the form of `list of tuples` as you can see above.

So when the user clicks the submit button i displaying the records in the form of the `table` by directing to the `/url` that renders template `recordslist.html`

now the above process is working fine. But here the `list of tuples/records` may up to `200 or more`, so i want to implement `pagination` for `/url` page.

I have googled a lot and all hits are found for retreiving the records from database, but not from the list, i am really confused on how to paginate the results with `10 pages for page`.

So can anyone please let me now how to paginate the results/records from list from the above code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Get the Page

Firstly, you would have to pull the page out of the request from the user. Assuming that you will use a page querystring parameter, you can use this to determine the page number:

```
params = web.input()
page = params.page if hasattr(params, 'page') else 1
```

#### Use the Page

Once you have a page, all that pagination involves is returning a slice of results.  The following function should give you the slices required (assuming that pages are 1-indexed):

```
def get_slices(page, page_size=10):
    return (page_size * (page - 1), (page_size * page)
```

This will return the lower and upper bound that you can use to slice your results list. So where you currently `return render.recordslist(result_list)`, you could instead use:

```
lower, upper = get_slices(page)
return render.recordslist(result_list[lower:upper])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, actually i am very newbie to web development, i am unable to understand the concept of getting the page of the request and some technical words from above, i request you to please incorporate in my above code with your style, so that i can understand the concept practically by viewing it...

Comment: Shiva, I've clarified and expanded my instructions.

Comment: k thanks, but how can we mention this in html i mean implementation of the url structure to get query strings in web.py ? , because we should options for like <previous> <next> , can u please instruct me(dont mind:)) in my above template code home.html ?

Comment: Unfortunately, my web.py knowledge does not extend that far. You'll have to pass the previous and next page numbers in to the template and use that to render your links.